# Should I extract functionality from this model class into a form class? (ActiveRecord Pattern)

Tags: model-view-controller, database-design, web-applications, sqlalchemy, pyramid

I am in the midst of designing an application following the mvc paradigm. I'm using the sqlalchemy expression language (not the orm), and pyramid if anyone was curious.

So, for a user class, that represents a user on the system, I have several accessor methods for various pieces of data like the avatar_url, name, about, etc. I have a  method called getuser which looks up a user in the db(by name or id), retrieves the users row, and encapsulates it with the user class.

However, should I have to make this look-up every-time I create a user class? What if a user is viewing her control panel and wants to change avatars, and sends an xhr; isn't it a waste to have to create a user object, and look up the users row when they wont even be using the data retrieved; but simply want to make a change to subset of the columns? I doubt this lookup is negligible despite indexing because of waiting for i/o correct?

More generally, isn't it inefficient to have to query a database and load *all* a model class's data to make any change (even small ones)?

I'm thinking I should just create a seperate form class (since every change made is via some form), and have specific form classes inherit them, where these setter methods will be implemented. What do you think?

EX: Class: Form <- Class: Change_password_form <- function: change_usr_pass

I'd really appreciate some advice on creating a proper design;thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**SQLAlchemy ORM** has some facilities which would simplify your task. It looks like you're having to re-invent quite some wheels already present in the ORM layer: "I have a method called getuser which looks up a user in the db(by name or id), retrieves the users row, and encapsulates it with the user class" - this is what ORM does.

- With ORM, you have a Session, which, apart from other things, serves as a cache for ORM objects, so you can avoid loading the same model more than once per transaction. You'll find that you need to load User object to authenticate the request anyway, so not querying the table at all is probably not an option.
- You can also configure some attributes to be [lazily loaded](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_7/orm/loading.html?highlight=lazy#sqlalchemy.orm.lazyload), so some rarely-needed or bulky properties are only loaded when you access them
- You can also configure relationships to be [eagerly loaded](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_7/orm/loading.html?highlight=eagerload#using-loader-strategies-lazy-loading-eager-loading) in a single query, which may save you from doing hundreds of small separate queries. I mean, in your current design, how many queries would the below code initiate:

  ```
  for user in get_all_users():
      print user.get_avatar_uri()
      print user.get_name()
      print user.get_about()
  ```

from your description it sounds like it may require 1 + (num_users*3) queries. With SQLAlchemy ORM you could load everything in a single query.

The conclusion is: fetching a single object from a database by its primary key is a reasonably cheap operation, you should not worry about that unless you're building something the size of facebook. What you should worry about is making hundreds of small separate queries where one larger query would suffice. This is the area where SQLAlchemy ORM is very-very good.

Now, regarding "isn't it a waste to have to create a user object, and look up the users row when they wont even be using the data retrieved; but simply want to make a change to subset of the columns" - I understand you're thinking about something like

```
class ChangePasswordForm(...):

    def _change_password(self, user_id, new_password):
         session.execute("UPDATE users ...", user_id, new_password)

    def save(self, request):
         self._change_password(request['user_id'], request['password'])
```

versus

```
class ChangePasswordForm(...):

    def save(self, request):
         user = getuser(request['user_id'])
         user.change_password(request['password'])
```

The former example will issue just one query, the latter will have to issue a SELECT and build User object, and then to issue an UPDATE. The latter may seem to be "twice more efficient", but in a real application the difference *may be* negligible. Moreover, often you will need to fetch the object from the database anyway, either to do validation (new password can not be the same as old password), permissions checks (is user Molly allowed to edit the description of Photo #12343?) or logging.

If you think that the difference of doing the extra query is going to be important (millions of users constantly editing their profile pictures) then you probably need to do some profiling and see where the bottlenecks are.

Comment: Thanks. The way I designed it before had it loading the whole user row once any query was necessary (indeed, a page would rarely need just one attribute from the user table, it would usually need multiple pieces of data). So the example you have here would necessitate one query. My user object encapsulates a collection of the user's attributes(the user's row), and via the getters, formats them appropriately(if needed) before providing access to them. All the data is loaded only once if an attribute is needed from the user table.

Comment: Like I mentioned above, I'm only using the sqla expression language, and I think its great(and sufficient). Objects like the user class in this example serve as DOA objects and I basically use them as interfaces to code against, separating certain details from the view.

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I was thinking; I should've written out the pseudo-code. Thinking about it now, either approach will generate the same query when its time to make the change, it's just a matter of which object issues it. If the former approach in the example produces one less query, then why not just do it that way, since the alternative has no significant benefit right(unless I'm overlooking something)? As for the logging and verification, I think its best to do them expressly? Thanks for your feedback; and apologies, I could have written things a bit clearer.

Answer (score 0):

Read up on the [SOLID principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID_%28object-oriented_design%29), paying particular attention to the **S** as it answers your question.

Create a single class to perform user existence check, and **inject** it into any class that **requires** that functionality.

Also, you need to create a data persistence class to store the user's data, so that the database doesn't have to be queried every time.